# The growth of English

Tags: vocabulary, history, loanwords

English is (to her credit) widely considered a language of .. mixed breeding, seeing as to how she accepts favours from just about anybody and everybody. What I'd like to know is how and by how much has the vocabulary grown since the late Middle Ages (~15th century Middle English)? This was before Shakespeare, the Renaissance, colonialism, and well, science & technology. Are there any related statistics available on this subject, and perhaps also on the number of loanwords in modern English?

Comment: Can you give a more precise definition of "the vocabulary of English"? A precise definition should serve as a clear test to establish whether or not a word belongs to this vocabulary. A few examples: "every word ever uttered by a native speaker of English in a conversation with a fellow native speaker that was not wholly in a foreign language", or "all entries in the Oxford English Dictionary combined", or "any word that is currently understood by at least 1 % of all native speakers of English". Then you need a criterion for "native speaker" too: are Indians included? Singaporeans? Americans?

Comment: Scope too broad for Q&A on englishSE. Suggest limiting the Q. to say, 'any useful references/ pointers to relevant information?' So one could go from there and carry out one's own research.

Comment: @Cerberus: I've now scoped the question to the OED & Webster. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kris: That's more or less what I have asked: "how much has the vocabulary grown by?" and "are there any statistics on the growth and on the number of loanwords in Modern English (preferably by language/country)?". Is that not narrow enough?

Comment: Shakespeare used 31534 words, and statistical techniques indicate that probably knew more than twice as many. Now, all you have to do is decide how many English words Shakespeare didn't know (there was a large number of technical words in various trades back then, so probably a lot), and how many words are in the English language today. I don't think the number of non-technical words has grown that much since Shakespeare's time—60,000 is a large vocabulary.

Comment: Of course, it all depends what you mean by a 'word'.

Comment: @PeterShor Precisely. Moreover, he conjured up a few thousand as probably did Dickens. I'm curious as to whether there has been any etymological mining performed to tabulate the growth of the vocabulary.

Comment: @BarrieEngland :D

Comment: The OED is heavily biased towards words that were known during the 19th and 20th centuries, as any modern dictionary necessarily is.

Comment: Have you tried googling 'growth of Engish vocabulary'?

Comment: This visual that the wording of the first sentence in this question conjures up is precisely why I'm glad that English doesn't typically use genders on inanimate objects.

Comment: @T.E.D., I don't totally understand your comment; perhaps my visual is different. Anyhow, mixed metaphor is a problem in the first sentence.  Based on the sense of the rest of the sentence, I'd expect the words *easy virtue* instead of *mixed breeding*.

Comment: No need for down or close votes. Let some ideas/ leads come in, and maybe, that can help everyone here as well, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your questions, chapter 6 (by John Algeo) of **The Cambridge History of the English Language: 1776-1997** ([ISBN 0521264774](http://books.google.com/books?id=NxHuNOvwt7wC&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=isbn+0521264774&source=bl&ots=_qf9sNDgee&sig=3pc1fIxAErbvmTvF_0b4BjIRbHI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zokFUJGWM4bPqgGJuMXDCA&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=isbn%200521264774&f=false)) provides a few statistics as well as extensive background information about English vocabulary.  See particularly section 2.2, "The growth of the vocabulary", and subsections 2.2.1, "The size of the vocabulary" and 2.2.3, "Gauging changes in the size of the vocabulary".  As noted in the middle paragraph of the following snippet, about 3/4 of the 80000+ words listed in Finkenstaedt et al's **Chronological English Dictionary** are post-Middle English ([M.E.](http://www.etymonline.com/abbr.php?allowed_in_frame=0) is the English language as written and spoken c.1100-c.1500.)  I've left portions of adjacent paragraphs visible to reinforce Algeo's warnings that these statistics are subject to systematic bias.

[image: page 63 of ISBN 0521264774]

Comment: Thank you, I'll look this up further :) I'm additionally also hoping to find a resource that tabulates the list of loanwords in English based on source language, country and date.